# Export map in openLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to export an 2.13.1 openLayers map into a canvas, but the methods to do so seem to have vanished.

The old methods would work like:

```
var exportMapControl = new OpenLayers.Control.ExportMap();
map.addControl(exportMapControl);

var canvas = OpenLayers.Util.getElement("exportedImage");
exportMapControl.trigger(canvas);
```

Does anyone know how this works for 2.13.1?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I am facing the same issue... This is not working for my code, I have added `ExportMap.js` and `Grid.js`, I am using WMS layers only, but answered solution is not working for me... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't write the whole function here (as it's already on two stack sites), but [this solution using html2canvas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/148862/39845) allows you to export a dataURL for your **OpenLayers 2** map.

In my app - I then use the dataURL to add the map to a pdf using [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf).

WMS, Vector and base layers are exported in this solution.

There appears to be better canvas support in OL3, as mentioned in my linked answer - I've seen a pretty convincing toBlob demo for OL3.

Answer (score 2):

The `ExportMap` control was actually never a part of the official OpenLayers distribution (you can confirm that by checking out [the project on github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) and browsing history). The example above comes from a sandbox that seems to be a user-submitted enhancement proposal ([demo here](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html)).

The [source of this custom control is available HERE](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/ExportMap.js).
Simply import it after loading OL 2.13.1 and it should be available as `OpenLayers.Control.ExportMap` again. Unless some other part of OL it depends on changed in the meantime it should work as it used to.